# using knockout.js with django forms?

Tags: django, knockout.js

I am looking to add some structure to my client side code and have been reading about `knockout.js`. I have been reading the documentations and have a simple question to ask - since knockout requires the user to add a `data-bind` attributes to the html elements, what is the best way for it to work with `django` forms, since currently I am using `{{ form.as_p }}`

I am curious how and where should I form's inputs to the `view model` (if it is in the form fields in Django, or forfeiting `{{ form.as_p }}` and type out in html instead.

Answer (score 19):

You can add custom attributes to your fields in the Form's Meta definition with widgets.

```
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        widgets = {'field_name1': forms.Textarea(attrs={'data-bind':'value: field1'}),
                   'field_name2': forms.TextInput(attrs={'data-bind':'value: field2'})}
```

For example, the first field would be rendered:

```
<textarea id="id_field_name1" name="field_name1" data-bind="value: field1"></textarea>
```

**Update:**
as a bonus here is an easy way to change an attribute for every field in a form, for example if they all need a specific class (helpful for other js addons or css styling)

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for name, field in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'some_form_field'
            # this could be used in your case if the Django field name is the
            # same as the KO.js field name
            field.widget.attrs['data-bind'] = 'value: %s' % name
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use [django-crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/) and define `data-bind` attributes in the [layout](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layouts.html):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Div('field_1',
            Field('field_2', data_bind='value: field_2')),
        HTML("{% if success %} <p data-bind="css: { success: success_flag }">Operation was successful</p> {% endif %}"),
    )
```

Then in the template you only do:

```
{% crispy form form.helper %}
```

and voila.

Cripsy-forms is even more powerful than that and allows you to define your own [layout templates](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layouts.html#overriding-layout-objects-templates) etc.